# How do I determine some function if domain and range are already specified?

Tags: functions

In one of my college interviews, I was asked to define a function whose domain is (0,1) and range is (-1,1). This can be very well answered (we can modify 'x' in cos(x)). I did encounter certain questions where domain is some half open interval and range is R (real line). In general, how do we determine such functions?
How about a function mapping from (0,1) to [0,1]?

Comment: The possibilities are endless -- I don't think you can find any good characterization of such functions even if you require them to be continuous or otherwise "nice". The simplest is probably $x\mapsto 2x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First scale $x$ properly, then use $\tan x$. For example, what is the domain and range of $\tan (ax+b)$?